# Get two different limits from mysql left join

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php-5.6

I want to display up to 3 posts form each category. Also I want to check each category have at least 3 posts (get the post count). Please see the table stretcher below

Category table

```
+---------+---------------+
| cat_id  | cat_name      |
+---------+---------------+
|       1 | cat name 1    |
|       2 | cat name 2    |
|       3 | cat name 3    |
+---------+---------------+
```

Posts table

```
+------+--------+-------+
| p_id | post   | c_id  |
+------+--------+-------+
|    1 | post 1 |   1   |
|    2 | post 2 |   1   |
|    3 | post 3 |   2   |
|    4 | post 1 |   2   |
|    5 | post 2 |   1   |
|    6 | post 3 |   3   |
|    6 | post 3 |   1   |
+------+--------+-------+
```

Query

```
if($results=$mysqli->query( SELECT * FROM categories LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.p_id= categories.cat_id WHERE posts.p_id= categories.cat_id ORDER BY cat_id LIMIT 0, 10")){
    while($row = mysqli_fecth_array($results)){
         //Do stuff
      }
    $results ->close();
  }
```

Any example or comments are appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't you be joining the category id in table Posts (c_id) with the cat_id in table Category? See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: So google "$results=$mysqli->query". What does every single result returned have that your code is missing?

Comment: If that's your real code; you have a quote missing in here `query( SELECT` - notice syntax highlighting? and this is a big typo `mysqli_fecth_array`

Comment: And, if you really want an OUTER JOIN, change 'WHERE' to 'AND'

Comment: that pending edit http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12419436 is modifying the code, why? @Dinesh Bhojvani how do you know that isn't her real code? and one guy approved. df?

Comment: Hey Sherry, that code you posted. Is that what you're really using here? few typos in there and somebody's wanting to fix it in an edit and how do we know that isn't the real problem here? you need to speak up here. Your question's getting voted to be closed due to a typo.

Comment: @I.G. Pascual why do you approve stuff just because? points gain?? How do we know that isn't what the real code is here?

Comment: ok I'm outta here. You guys deal with this mess.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get up to 3 posts from each category in MySQL and sane query. You need support for window functions for that. I would preform a separate query for each category. You can read short info in this tag: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/window-functions/info

For the second part:

```
SELECT c_id, COUNT(*) FROM posts GROUP BY c_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

select    distinct    (c.postid)    ,    c.postname,    s.category_name    from    posts    c    inner    join    category    s    on    s.cat_id    =    c.cat_id    group    by    c.cat_id    having    COUNT(c.cat_id)    >    3    limit    3